# Is the desktop environment responsible for affecting behaviour to certain keys?

Tags: arch-linux, window-manager, desktop-environment, openbox, key-mapping

I have a laptop which has a `Fn` key. Using `xev` command shows that `Fn + UpArrow` is affected to `XF86AudioRaiseVolume`.

If I use KDE, is it KDE that is responsible for affecting a behaviour to that symbol?

I have Arch linux installed with openbox and this key (and other `Fn + ...`) does not work.

On Ubuntu + KDE, it works.

I was wondering if it was my responsability to configure Openbox in Arch linux to provide those keys with a behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Gnome and KDE provide some of their own keyboard shortcuts in addition to the ones provided by their respective WMs.

However, this may not mean what you think. The fact that `Fn + UpArrow` produces the keysym `XF86AudioRaiseVolume` is mainly due to your laptop's keyboard. You can verify this by using `xev` again (in the Openbox environment); It should have the same output when you press `Fn + UpArrow`.

In Openbox, what is different is that there is not a binding setup for `XF86AudioRaiseVolume`, so nothing happens when that virtual 'key' is pressed: The keysym is sent, Openbox isn't interested in it, so nothing happens.

You may want to look into adding your own bindings with `xbindkeys` (see http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/ ). There's a good [article on the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys) about it.
The program you want to bind to may be `amixer` (if you're using ALSA), and / or `pactl` (if you're using PulseAudio).